# Can I backup my ICloud documents with TimeMachine to my TimeCapsule?

Tags: icloud

I want my docs en pics in the cloud but also a backup. Want to backup to a TimeCapsule with TimeMachine (or if necessairy an other softwareprogram). Wonder if that’s possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible (requiring no interaction), however you need to make sure that "Optimize Mac Storage" is not enabled and that all your files are downloaded. If they're not downloaded, they won't get backed up.

Comment: Thanks! Going to try that as soon as my MacMini has arrived. Working in a Windows pc now combineren with iPone and iPad.